# In Haskell how can you multiply a string?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that takes a `String` and an `Int` and returns that string "int" times. That is:

```
duplicate :: String -> Int -> String
```

If I were to write `duplicate "Hello" 3` the output should be `"HelloHelloHello"`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Easily:

```
duplicate :: String -> Int -> String
duplicate string n = concat $ replicate n string
```

The `$` is [a function of type `(a -> b) -> a -> b`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%24). The language allows the functions with non-alpha-numeric names to be used in infix form (as operators). I.e., the body of the function above is absolutely identical to the following expression:

```
($) concat (replicate n string)
```

What `$` does is just allows you to get rid of braces. Meaning that the above expressions are just an alternative to the following expression:

```
concat (replicate n string)
```

Comment: That's great thanks! I've seen concat used before and that was my first guess... but what does the $ sign do in this situation?

Comment: @benharris The `$` operation is simply function application. Only it has the lowest precedence and it's right associative instead of left associative.

Comment: You should change the type signature of `duplicate` to `[a] -> Int -> [a]`. That way you can use it for any list.

Comment: @AaditMShah It would make sense to flip the arguments too. Not creating such a basic compositional function at all is also an option. The question is how many subjects we want to touch while explaining trivial stuff. It's pretty easy to overburden a beginner.

Comment: True. It makes sense to have `n` as the first argument as that allows you to compose functions like `putStrLn . duplicate 3`. On that note, @benharris, I think you should read [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: Am I missing something? Tried this exact thing and did not work. Not in ghci nor loading script.

Comment: @JessieRichardson Most likely you have an issue in something else. Post a dedicated question.

Answer (score 8):

A `String` is just a synonym for a list of `Char`, and the list type is a `Monad`. Therefore

```
duplicate :: Int -> String -> String
duplicate n str = [1..n] >>= const str
```

Or, if you wanted to get all point-free

```
duplicate = (. const) . (>>=) . enumFromTo 1
```

---

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments

```
duplicate n str = [1..n] >> str
```

or

```
duplicate = (>>) . enumFromTo 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `replicate` and `concat` as follows:

```
duplicate :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
duplicate = flip $ (concat .) . replicate

-- or as larsmans suggested:

duplicate :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
duplicate = (concat .) . flip replicate
```

Then use it as `duplicate "Hello" 3`.

Comment: Shorter: `(concat .) . flip replicate`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I confused it with something to be. I'll delete the comment.

Comment: This is a classic example of pointless pointfree. Can you tell me, at a glance, why the `(.)` are there in the places they are? What are they doing? Why are they necessary? On the other hand, `let (.:) = fmap fmap fmap in concat .: flip replicate` is an example of the use of `fmap fmap fmap`, or `(.).(.)`, to compose functions with two arguments. This is an idiom you can reuse elsewhere, not just the output of running `pointfree`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Indeed. If you're interested in taking pointfree programming to the extreme then take a look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20279307/783743

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern matching.

```
duplicate _ 0 = []
duplicate xs n = xs ++ duplicate xs (n-1)
```

or

```
duplicate xs n  | n==0 = []
                | otherwise = xs ++ duplicate xs (n-1)
```

Comment: This is exactly equivalent to `concat .: flip replicate` except inlined. I suspect that they'd compile to the same core when optimized.

Comment: Actually that's a great answer for a beginner who doesn't know about monads, point-free style, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Again a beginners attempt, using recursion

`duplicate s n = if n <= 1 then s else duplicate (n-1) s ++ s`

though it is a little unclear what the function should do if n is negative or zero. So I chose to return the string itself.