# ($) is to (.) as `fmap` is to?

Tags: haskell, functor, pointfree

I have a function `funcM :: a -> b -> c -> IO (x, y)`

I want to write a function `funcM_ :: a-> b-> c-> IO x` so:

```
funcM_ = fst `fmap` funcM -- error
```

I could add back all the points, but it seems like there should be something I could replace `fmap` with so that the above will work. Kind of like replacing ($) with (.) would make this work in a pure context.

What is the function I am looking for?

Answer (score 7):

Since you’re composing a one-argument function (`fmap`) with a three-argument function (`funcM`), you need three levels of composition:

```
funcM_ = ((fmap fst .) .) . funcM
```

This is equivalent to the pointed version by a simple expansion:

```
funcM_ x = (fmap fst .) . funcM x
funcM_ x y = fmap fst . funcM x y
funcM_ x y z = fmap fst (funcM x y z)
```

This follows from the type of `fmap`, really:

```
fmap :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You’re just partially applying the arguments to `funcM` so that you have an `f a` (here `IO (x, y)`) which you give to `fmap fst` to get back an `f b` (`IO x`).

As an aside, `M_` usually implies returning `m ()`.

Comment: And in fact it is returning () In order not to have to list a lot of code, I changed the Monad in question from `StateT Context (ErrorT Err STM) a` to IO. I still need the state but I don't need the value. The a and b arguments actually are used to create the state and the c value implements recoverable errors.  All details that are unimportant to the question.  Yes, it looks like I also need `snd` rather then `fst`. but it doesn't matter for the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279307/783743 It explains how to convert your code into pointfree style. Let's start with a non-pointfree definition of `funcM_`:

```
funcM_ a b c = fmap fst (funcM a b c)

-- But `\x -> f (g x)` is `f . g`. Hence:

funcM_ a b = fmap fst . (funcM a b)

-- But `\x -> f (g x)` is `f . g`. Hence:

funcM_ a = (fmap fst .) . (funcM a)

-- But `\x -> f (g x)` is `f . g`. Hence:

funcM_ = ((fmap fst .) .) . funcM
```

Another way to do this would be to use `uncurry` and `curry` as follows:

```
uncurry3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (a, b, c) -> d
uncurry3 f (a, b, c) = f a b c

curry3 :: ((a, b, c) -> d) -> a -> b -> c -> d
curry3 f a b c = f (a, b, c)

(.::) :: (d -> e) -> (a -> b -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> c -> e
f .:: g = curry3 (f . (uncurry3 g))
```

Now you can write `funcM_` as follows:

```
funcM_ = fmap fst .:: funcM
```

You could also write `.::` in pointfree style as follows:

```
(.::) :: (d -> e) -> (a -> b -> c -> d) -> a -> b -> c -> e
(.::) = (.) . (.) . (.)
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: FYI `(.::)` is defined in functors: Data.Functor.Syntax http://hackage.haskell.org/package/functors-0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Syntax.html

(I suppose you already know that, or else the name `(.::)` is naturally attractive.)

Comment: I guess you mean `funcM_ = fmap fst .:: funcM`.

Comment: @TomEllis Yes, indeed. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Add a dot for each argument to `funcM`

These are all equivalent:

```
((fmap fst . ) .) . funcM
((.)  . (.)  . (.))  (fmap fst) funcM
(fmap . fmap . fmap) (fmap fst) funcM

import Data.Functor.Syntax -- from 'functors' package
(.::) (fmap fst) funcM
```

Note that all I did was change the implicit `($)` to `(.)`. 
:-)

`(.)` is the implementation of `fmap` for the function instance of `Functor` :

```
instance Functor ((->) a) b where
  fmap f g = f . g
```

GHCi `:t` is your friend.