# Where did bind come from?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, pointfree

Using lambdabot's pl plug-in,

```
let iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x) in iterate
```

is converted to

```
fix ((ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<))
```

What does the `(=<<)` mean here? I thought that it is only used with monads.

Comment: Yes. And functions form a monad. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short, straightforward [combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic)-style  derivation:

```
iterate f x 
   = x : iterate f (f x) 
   = (:) x ((iterate f . f) x)
   = ap (:) (iterate f . f) x            -- ap g f x = g x (f x)       (1)
   = ap (:) ((.) (iterate f) f) x
   = ap (:) ( ((.) =<< iterate) f) x     -- (g =<< f) x = g (f x) x    (2)
   = ap (:) ( ((.) =<<) iterate f) x
   = ((ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<)) iterate f x 
       -- ((f .) . g) x y = (f .) (g x) y = (f . g x) y = f (g x y)    (3)
```

so, by eta-contraction,

```
iterate = ((ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<)) iterate
        = fix ((ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<))    -- fix f = x where x = f x   (4)
```

QED. (1) and (2) come from what you ask about, functions as monads, already explained in Chris's answer:

```
  ap :: (Monad m) => m (a->b) ->   m a  ->  m b              m ~ (r ->)
  that's            (r->a->b) -> (r->a) -> r->b 
  so            ap     g           f       x   = g x (f x)

  (=<<) :: (Monad m) => (a-> m b) ->   m a  ->  m b          m ~ (r ->)
  that's                (a->r->b) -> (r->a) -> r->b
  so            (=<<)      g           f       x   = g (f x) x
```

(3) is discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972422/how-does-haskells-boobs-operator-work-in-plain-non-functional-english) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279306/what-does-f-g-mean-in-haskell) at length.

Answer (score 13):

Let's start with the definition

```
iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)
```

We want to convert this to point-free form. We can proceed step-by-step, but to understand it, you first have to know that

### Functions form a monad

Or, more specifically, the type constructor `(->) r`, which you should think of as "functions from type `r`" or `(r ->)`, is a monad. The best way to see it is to define the return and bind operations. The general form for a monad `m` is

```
return :: a -> m a
(>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Specialized to functions, you have

```
return :: a -> r -> a
(>>=)  :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> r -> b
```

and you can convince yourself that the only sensible definitions are

```
return x = \r -> x -- equivalent to 'const x'
f >>=  g = \r -> g (f r) r
```

This is completely equivalent to the [Reader monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html), also called the environment monad. The idea is that you have an additional parameter of type `r` (sometimes called the environment) which is being threaded through the computation - every function implicitly receives `r` as an additional argument.

Now we know everything we need to start making our function pointless.

### Getting rid of recursion with `fix`

First thing is to remove the recursive reference to `iterate`. We can do this using `fix`, which has the definition

```
fix :: (t -> t) -> t
fix f = f (fix f)
```

You can think of `fix` as the canonical recursive function, in that it can be used to define other recursive functions. The standard idiom is to define a non-recursive function `g` with an additional argument called `func`, which represents the function that you'd like to define. Applying `fix` to `g` computes the fixed point of `g`, which is the recursive function that you wanted.

```
iterate = fix g where g func f x = x : func f (f x)
```

We can convert this to lambda form

```
iterate = fix (\func f x -> x : func f (f x))
        = fix (\func f x -> (:) x (func f (f x)))
```

where the second line is just removed the infix `:` and replacing it with a prefix `(:)`. Now that there are no self-references, we can proceed.

### Removing some of the points with `ap`

We can use `ap` to pull out the references to `x`. The type of `ap` is

```
ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

It takes a function in some monadic context, and applies it to a value in another monadic context. Note that this is already using the fact that functions `(->) r` form a monad! Specializing `m` to `(->) r` you get

```
ap :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

The only way to make the types work out is if `ap` (specialized to functions) has the following definition

```
ap f g = \r -> f r (g r)
```

so that you use the second function `g` to build the second argument to the first function `f`. Note that this definition of `ap` is exactly equivalent to the combinator *S* in the [SKI combinator calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus).

For us, this allows us to feed the parameter `x` to the first function `(:)` and use another function `\y -> func f (f y)` to build the second argument, which is the tail of the list. As a plus, we can then remove all refernce to `x` using eta reduction.

```
iterate = fix (\func f x -> ap (:) (\y -> func f (f y)) x)
        = fix (\func f   -> ap (:) (\y -> func f (f y))  )
```

We can now remove the reference to `y` as well, by recognizing that `func f (f y)` is just the composition of `func f` and `y`.

```
iterate = fix (\func f   -> ap (:) (      func f . f)    )
```

### Threading arguments through with `(>>=)`

Now we have the expression `(func f . f)`, or `(.) (func f) f` if we use prefix notation. We'd like to describe this as some function applied to `f`, but that requires that we thread `f` into the expression in two places.

Fortunately, this is exactly what the monad instance for `(->) r` does! This makes total sense if you remember that the function monad is exactly equivalent to the reader monad, and the job of the reader monad is to thread an additional parameter into every function call.

The definition of bind specialized to functions is

```
f >>= g = \r -> g (f r) r
```

The parameter `r` is first threaded through the left-hand argument of the bind, whose result is used by the right-hand argument to create a function that can consume another `r`. The mnemonic is that the parameter `r` is first threaded through the left argument, then through the right argument.

In our case we write `(.) (func f) f = (func >>= (.)) f` to get (using eta reduction)

```
iterate = fix (\func f   -> ap (:)  ((func >>= (.)) f))
        = fix (\func     -> ap (:) . (func >>= (.))   )
```

### Chaining compositions

Finally, we use another trick, repeated composition, to pull out the parameter `func`. The idea is that if you have an expression

```
f . g a
```

then you can replace it with

```
f . g a = (.) f (g a)
        = (((.) f) . g) a
        = ((f .) . g) a
```

So you have expressed it as a function applied to an argument (ready for eta reduction!). In our case that means making the replacement

```
iterate = fix (\func     -> (ap (:) .) . (>>= (.)) func)
        = fix (            ((ap (:) .) . (>>= (.))     )
```

Finally, remove the inner brackets and describing the section with `(=<<)` instead of `(>>=)` gives

```
iterate = fix ((ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<))
```

which is the same expression that lambdabot came up with.

Comment: BTW the definition `fix f = f (fix f)` will (might?..) cause recalculation of `(fix f)` each *time* the recursive call is made; the definition `fix f = x where x = f x` will cause calculation of `fix f` at each *place* where the recursive call is made. It's the difference between (in Prolog) `rec(f(G)) :- rec(G).` and `rec(G) :- G=X, X=f(X).` or, in Lisp, `(defun rec () (cons 'f (rec)))` and `(defun rec () (let ((g (list 'f))) (setf (cdr g) g) g))`.

Comment: (sorry for the extra edit; I was sure it would get merged with the previous one, just 1 minute apart, but for some reason it didn't).

Comment: @WillNess - no idea who approved the typography-breaking edit in the first place, but I hadn't noticed it, so thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and the monad here is `((->) a)`: `iterate f x` obviously constructs a list, so the type of `iterate` is `(a->a)->a->[a]`, so given `(a->a)`, it produces `(a->[a])`

You can see that `ap` is given a function `(:) :: a->[a]->[a]`, which must be `m (a->b)`, so `m` here is `(->) a`.

```
(ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<) =
\f -> (ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<) $ f =
\f -> ap (:) . ((.) =<< f) = -- at this stage we can see =<< is of (->) a monad,
                       -- whose bind is the S-combinator: s f g x = f (g x) x
\f -> ap (:) . (f >>= (.)) =
\f g -> ap (:) (f g . g) = -- ok, ap is also the S-combinator with some
                           -- arguments swapped around
-- you see, for monad ((->) r), ap needs function of type (r->(a->b)) = (r->a->b)
-- whereas >>= needs (a->(r->b)) = (a->r->b) - the same function flipped
\f g -> (flip (:)) =<< (f g . g) =
\f g -> \x -> x : (f g $ g x)
```

This is a function of two arguments, `a->(b->c)`, so when it is passed to `fix :: (a->a)->a`, it must be that `a=(b->c)`, and `fix (ap...) :: b->c`. In its turn, since this all is the same as `iterate`, it must be that `b->c = (x->x)->(x->[x])`, so `b=(x->x)`, and `c=(x->[x])`

Indeed:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t ((ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<))
((ap (:) .) . ((.) =<<))
  :: (Monad ((->) (a -> b)), Monad ((->) a)) =>
     ((a -> b) -> b -> [a]) -> (a -> b) -> a -> [a]
```

which will bind `b=a` after passing to `fix`.

Now, `fix` supplies the first argument to the above like so:

```
fix h = let x = h x in x
hence, iterate = fix h = let iterate = h iterate in iterate 
-- supply iterate as the first
-- argument to the function passed to fix
```

so we have:

```
iterate =
fix (\f g -> \x -> x : (f g $ g x)) =
\g x -> x : (iterate g $ g x)
```