# Why does this point free definition not work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I tried to make the following function definition:

```
relativelyPrime x y = gcd x y == 1
```

point-free:

```
relativelyPrime = (== 1) . gcd
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘a -> Bool’
Expected type: (a -> a) -> a -> Bool
  Actual type: (a -> a) -> Bool
Relevant bindings include
  relativelyPrime :: a -> a -> Bool (bound at 1.hs:20:1)
In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(== 1)’
In the expression: (== 1) . gcd
In an equation for ‘relativelyPrime’:
    relativelyPrime = (== 1) . gcd
```

I don't quite understand. `gcd` takes two Ints/Integer, returns one Ints/Integer, then that one Int/Integer is checked for equality to '1'. I don't see where my error is.

Comment: well `gcd` there will produce another function if given only one argument - and in your point-free version you hand this *function*  on to `(== 1)` which of course does not know how to handle functions ;)

Comment: maybe you understand when you first *remove*  one *point* : `relativePrime x = (== 1) . gcd x` this works! Now you cannot *remove*  `x` anymore as it is *tied* to fast to `gcd` - you could if you had `(== 1) $ gcd x`

Comment: @Carsten's comment is correct. One option would be to use `uncurry` to turn `gcd` into a single-argument function (taking a tuple of two integers).

Comment: @psmears exactly `curry ((== 1) . (uncurry gcd))` should work ... but really IMO now point-free is point-less as the original version was easy to read and understand - this one is cluttered with useless parts just to make it point-free

Comment: @Carsten It does work indeed and I understand my error now. Feel free to expand this into an answer, since I think it deserves an up vote and accepted answer mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work because `gcd` requires two inputs whereas function composition only provides `gcd` one input. Consider the definition of function composition:

```hs
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Hence, the expression `(== 1) . gcd` is equivalent to:

```hs
\x -> (== 1) (gcd x)
```

This is not what you want. You want:

```hs
\x y -> (== 1) (gcd x y)
```

You could define a new operator to compose a unary function with a binary function:

```hs
f .: g = \x y -> f (g x y)
```

Then, your expression becomes:

```hs
relativelyPrime = (== 1) .: gcd
```

In fact, the `(.:)` operator can be defined in terms of function composition:

```hs
(.:) = (.) . (.)
```

It looks kind of like an owl, but they are indeed equivalent. Thus, another way to write the expression:

```hs
relativelyPrime = ((== 1) .) . gcd
```

If you want to understand what's happening then see: [What does (f .) . g mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279306/783743)

Answer (score 5):

as you commented on it - if you really want a point-free version you can first use `uncurry gcd` to transform `gcd` into a version that accepts a single input (a tuple):

```
Prelude> :t uncurry gcd
uncurry gcd :: Integral c => (c, c) -> c
```

then check with `(== 1)` and finally `curry` it again for the original signature:

```
relativeelyPrime = curry ((== 1) . (uncurry gcd))
```

your version did not work just because `gcd` produces a function if given only the first argument and this is no legal input for `(== 1)` which awaits a number.