# Error when trying to compose monadic functions

Tags: haskell, monads

I just learned about monads, and I've been trying to implement a lot of the functions in Control.Monad. I just got to `ap`, but I can't make it work. I made a function `almostAp :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m (m b)`, and I tried to compose it with another function I made, `flatten :: Monad m => m (m b) -> m b`. The problem is when I try to use `ap = flatten . almostAp`, I get

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: m ~ (->) (m a)
  Expected type: m (a -> b) -> m a -> m a -> m b
  Actual type: m (a -> b) -> m a -> m (m b)
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘almostAp’
In the expression: (flatten . almostAp)`
```

But, `(flatten .)` has type `Monad m => (a -> m (m b)) -> a -> m b` according to ghci, so why does this happen?

Here are the function definitions (I know I can clean them up with `=<<` and  the functor laws):

```
almostAp :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m (m b)
almostAp = (flip (\x -> fmap ($x))) . (fmap (flip (>>=))) . (fmap (return .))

flatten :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
flatten = (>>= id)
```

Comment: You seem very keen on point-free style, which makes your code rather hard to read (and, I can imagine, rather hard to write, too!) Don't be afraid of `let` bindings or `do` notation.

Comment: "`let` go of point-free style: only use it `where` it makes sense, and you will `do` better"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were getting your type error because you were trying to compose a **one-argument** function `flatten` (which, incidentally, usually goes by the name of [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join)) with a **two-argument** function `almostAp`. `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)` is meant for when the function on the right is a one-argument function. Unfortunately the error message was not very helpful.

`(.).(.)` (pronounced "*dot*-dot-*dot*", or "owl eyes") does what you want:

```
ghci> let ap = ((.).(.)) flatten almostAp
ghci> :t ap
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

But `ap` can be implemented much more simply with `do` notation. Is your version really easier to understand than this?

```
ap mf mx = do
    f <- mf
    x <- mx
    return (f x)
```

`do` notation is just syntactic sugar for `>>=`. Here's how it looks without it (though I much prefer the `do` version):

```
ap mf mx = mf >>= \f -> fmap f mx
```

Comment: `(.).(.)` is "owl eyes" in my mind, which seems rather more ... family friendly.

Answer (score 3):

> But, `(flatten .)` has type `Monad m => (a -> m (m b)) -> a -> m b` according to ghci, so why does this happen?

Indeed, it does. Consider:

```hs
flatten  :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a

almostAp :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m (m b)
```

Thus, the type of `(flatten .)` is:

```hs
flatten     :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a -- renaming a to b
                          |     |    | |
                          -------    ---
                             |        |
(.)         ::              (b    ->  c) -> (a ->    b)    -> a ->  c
                                                     |              |
                                                  -------          ---
                                                  |     |          | |
(flatten .) :: Monad m =>                   (a -> m (m b)) -> a -> m b
```

However, you can't apply `(flatten .)` to `almostAp` because the types are incompatible:

```hs
almostAp    :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m (m b)
                          |        |    |            |
                          ----------    --------------
                               |               |
                               |            -------
                               |            |     |
(flatten .) :: Monad m => (    a     ->     m (m b))   -> a -> m b
```

You expected this:

```hs
almostAp    :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m (m b)
                          |               |    |     |
                          -----------------    -------
                                  |               |
                                  |            -------
                                  |            |     |
(flatten .) :: Monad m => (       a         -> m (m b)) -> a -> m b
```

But, that's not the way [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) works. A function of the type `a -> b -> c` means `a -> (b -> c)` and not `(a -> b) -> c`. The first function `a -> (b -> c)` takes two arguments<sup>1</sup>, `a` and `b`, and returns `c`. The second function `(a -> b) -> c` takes one argument `a -> b` and returns `c`.

So, how do you compose `flatten` and `almostAp`? You can't do it using normal function composition because `almostAp` requires two arguments:

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
       |      |    |      |
       --------    --------
           |           |
        flatten        +-- almostAp can't be used because it needs two arguments
                        -- but (.) only gives it one argument (the `a` in a -> b)
```

We need a special composition operator to compose them:

```hs
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
        |      |    |           |
        --------    -------------
            |             |
         flatten      almostAp

(.:) f g x y = f (g x y)
```

Now, we can simply write `flatten .: almostAp`. Another way to write it would be `(flatten .) . almostAp`. This is because `(.:) = (.) . (.)`. Read the following for more details:

[What does (f .) . g mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279306/783743)

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, a function of the type `a -> (b -> c)` only takes one argument `a` and returns another function `b -> c` which takes the second argument `b` and returns `c`.