# Composite function takes multiple arguments

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, function-composition

This is my program:

```
boolToInt True  = 1
boolToInt False = 0

gt :: Int -> Int -> Int
gt x y = boolToInt $ (>) x y
```

I try refactoring `gt` with `gt = boolToInt . (>)` but getting an error:

> ‘(>)’ is applied to too few arguments

The only idea come to me is `curry` and `uncurry`, but I suppose it might make `gt` even more complicated than `gt x y = boolToInt $ (>) x y`.

Do I have a prettier *functional* solution to this composition?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279306/246886

Comment: You can uncurry `(>)`, then re-curry the result. `gt = curry (boolToInt . (uncurry (>)))`.

Answer (score 2):

The magical `pointfree.io` has come up with the following solution:

```
gt :: Int -> Int -> Int
gt = (boolToInt .) . (>)
```

Comment: Wow, http://pointfree.io is cool

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
(boolToInt .) . (>)
```