# How to define dot product in Haskell a pointfree style?

Tags: haskell, linear-algebra

Really, I'd like to figure out the more general solution of composing a fold with a zipwith in a single function point free.

```
zWMult :: Num c => [c] -> [c] -> [c]
zWMult = zipWith (*)

foldPl0 :: Num c => [c] -> c
foldPl0 = foldl (+) 0
```

I get the correct solution when I use arguements

```
dPr x y = foldPl0 (zWMult x y)
dPr x y = foldPl0 $ zWMult x y
```

But have no idea how to naturally compose these without arguments.  Both these fail:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let dPr1 :: Num c => [c] -> [c] -> c
Prelude|     dPr1 = fPl0 $ zWMult
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:171:19:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[[c] -> [c] -> c]’
            with actual type ‘[Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]’
Relevant bindings include
  dPr1 :: [c] -> [c] -> c (bound at <interactive>:171:5)
Probable cause: ‘zWMult’ is applied to too few arguments
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘zWMult’
In the expression: fPl0 $ zWMult

Prelude> :{
Prelude| let dPr1 :: Int c => [c] -> [c] -> c
Prelude|     dPr1 = foldPl0 $ zWMult
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:11:13:
‘Int’ is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for ‘dPr1’: dPr1 :: Int c => [c] -> [c] -> c
```

As well as

```
dPr2 = foldPl0 . zWMult
```

Edit: 
Cool, one should cross reference this post if you want a more complete understanding of the solution below.
[What does (f .) . g mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279306/what-does-f-g-mean-in-haskell)

Comment: You can use http://pointfree.io/ to convert to pointfree. Use with care, since pointfree easily turns into obfuscation.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with a simpler version:

```
dot x y = sum (zipWith (*) x y)
```

you can convert `\x -> f (g x)` with function composition to `f . g`:

```
dot x = sum . zipWith (*) x
```

`f . g` means `(.) f g`:

```
dot x = (sum.) (zipWith (*) x)
```

and you can convert `\x -> f (g x)` with function composition to `f . g`:

```
dot = (sum.) . zipWith (*)
```

Comment: While this `(f .) . g` idiom is a common point-free way to compose a 1-argument function with a 2-argument one, it can also be written `fmap sum . zipWith (*)` or even `fmap sum <$> zipWith (*)` which I find slightly more descriptive than partial application of `(.)`, since while `fmap` in the `(->)` functor is equivalent to composition, it illustrates the fact that you’re “mapping” over the result of a function by ignoring arguments (one `fmap` for each argument).