# fmap with two functions

Tags: haskell, neural-network, feed-forward

Im writing a neural network using haskell. Im basing my code on this http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/haskell/brain.html .
I adapted the feedforward method in the following way:

```
feedForward :: [Float] -> [([Float], [[Float]])] -> [Float]
feedForward = foldl ((fmap tanh . ) . previousWeights)
```

Where previousWeights is:

```
previousWeights :: [Float] -> ([Float], [[Float]]) -> [Float]
previousWeights actual_value (bias, weights) = zipWith (+) bias (map (sum.(zipWith (*) actual_value)) weights)
```

I don't really understand what `fmap tanh .` From what I read fmap applied to two functions is like a composition. If i change the `fmap` for `map` I get the same result.

Comment: For lists `fmap = map`. `fmap` is a generalization of `map`.

Comment: `fmap` is equal to `map` for List, see http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass, look for `fmap = map`

Comment: `(fmap tanh .)` gives you `(Floating b, Functor f) => (a -> f b) -> a -> f b` if you restrict it to lists by using map you get `(map tanh .) :: Floating b => (a -> [b]) -> a -> [b]`

Comment: For the `(.) .` have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279306/what-does-f-g-mean-in-haskell)

Comment: `(fmap tanh . ) . previousWeights` is a complicated way to write `\x y -> map tanh (previousWeights x y)`. Hence, it generates the previous weights and then takes the tanh of each of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does (f .) . g mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279306/what-does-f-g-mean-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to read if we give the parameters names and remove the consecutive `.`:

```hs
feedForward :: [Float] -> [([Float], [[Float]])] -> [Float]
feedForward actual_value bias_and_weights =
  foldl
  (\accumulator -- the accumulator, it is initialized as actual_value
    bias_and_weight -> -- a single value from bias_and_weights
     map tanh $ previousWeights accumulator bias_and_weight)
  actual_value -- initialization value
  bias_and_weights -- list we are folding over
```

It might also help to know that type signature of `foldl` in this case will be `([Float] -> ([Float], [[Float]])-> [Float]) -> [Float] -> [([Float], [[Float]])] -> [Float]`.

Note: This style of code you have found, while fun to write, can be a challenge for others to read and I generally do not recommend you write this way if for other than fun.