# Functional composition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition

I know this is quite possible since my Haskell friends seem to be able to do this kind of thing in their sleep, but I can't wrap my head around more complicated functional composition in JS.

Say, for example, you have these three functions:

```
const round = v => Math.round(v);

const clamp = v => v < 1.3 ? 1.3 : v;

const getScore = (iteration, factor) =>
    iteration < 2 ? 1 :
    iteration === 2 ? 6 :
    (getScore(iteration - 1, factor) * factor);
```

In this case, say `iteration` should be an integer, so we would want to apply `round()` to that argument. And imagine that `factor` must be at least `1.3`, so we would want to apply `clamp()` to that argument.

If we break `getScore` into two functions, this seems easier to compose:

```
const getScore = iteration => factor =>
    iteration < 2 ? 1 :
    iteration === 2 ? 6 :
    (getScore(iteration - 1)(factor) * factor);
```

The code to do this probably looks something like this:

```
const getRoundedClampedScore = compose(round, clamp, getScore);
```

But what does the compose function look like? And how is `getRoundedClampedScore` invoked? Or is this horribly wrong?

Comment: I think _"What does the compose function look like"_ is the wrong question. There is only one `compose` function and one shouldn't invent new `compose` functions to suit a specific situation.

Comment: @JLRishe I disagree. Normal function composition (i.e. `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`) is just the most basic form of function composition. There are more complex forms of function composition too such as `(c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d`. In this particular question, the form of function composition is `(a -> b -> c) -> (d -> a) -> (e -> b) -> d -> e -> c`. Now, more complex forms of function composition [can be decomposed into simpler forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279306/783743). Asking what the compose function looks like (and how to simplify it) is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `compose` function should probably take the core function to be composed *first*, using rest parameters to put the other functions into an array, and then return a function that calls the `i`th function in the array with the `i`th argument:

```js
const round = v => Math.round(v);

const clamp = v => v < 1.3 ? 1.3 : v;

const getScore = iteration => factor =>
    iteration < 2 ? 1 :
    iteration === 2 ? 6 :
    (getScore(iteration - 1)(factor) * factor);

const compose = (fn, ...transformArgsFns) => (...args) => {
  const newArgs = transformArgsFns.map((tranformArgFn, i) => tranformArgFn(args[i]));
  return fn(...newArgs);
}

const getRoundedClampedScore = compose(getScore, round, clamp);

console.log(getRoundedClampedScore(1)(5))
console.log(getRoundedClampedScore(3.3)(5))
console.log(getRoundedClampedScore(3.3)(1))
```

Comment: Typically, a `compose` function feeds data through the provided functions in the reverse of the order that they are provided. So in the case of `compose(getScore, round, clamp)` one would expect this to execute `clamp`, then `round`, then `getScore`. A utility function that feeds data through the functions from left to right would typically be called `pipe`.

Comment: Now that I look at your code a little more closely, the implementation you have there is nothing like `compose`. It's applying all of the functions except the first to each respective argument then feeding those results into the first function. That's not what a `compose` function does.

Comment: Simpler: `const compose = (f, ...fs) => (...xs) => f(...fs.map((f, i) => f(xs[i])));`.

Comment: This is the first time I've felt unqualified to accept any answer. My feeling is that my question was probably off target: I did not fully grasp the precise definition of `compose()` and was more asking generally about composition. That was sloppy. I like the function signature here and its simplicity (and especially @AaditMShah's shorthand), so this is probably the code I will end up using. I also very respectfully note @JLRishe's comment of dissent above. I'm genuinely grateful for the time you all put into this and I honestly want to award the answer to all three of you.

Answer (score 3):

I think part of the trouble you're having is that `compose` isn't actually the function you're looking for, but rather something else. `compose` feeds a value through a series of functions, whereas you're looking to pre-process a series of arguments, and then feed those processed arguments into a final function.

[Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) has a utility function that's perfect for this, called `converge`. What `converge` does is produce a function that applies a series of functions to a series of arguments on a 1-to-1 correspondence, and then feeds all of those transformed arguments into another function. In your case, using it would look like this:

```
var saferGetScore = R.converge(getScore, [round, clamp]);
```

If you don't want to get involved in a whole 3rd party library just to use this `converge` function, you can easily define your with a single line of code. It looks a lot like what CaptainPerformance is using in their answer, but with one fewer `...` (and you definitely shouldn't name it `compose`, because that's an entirely different concept):

```
const converge = (f, fs) => (...args) => f(...args.map((a, i) => fs[i](a)));

const saferGetScore = converge(getScore, [round, clamp]);
const score = saferGetScore(2.5, 0.3);
```

Comment: Simpler: `const converge = (f, fs) => (...args) => f(...fs.map((f, i) => f(args[i])));`.

Comment: @AaditMShah Thanks, I was shying away from cramming it all into one line, but seeeing it written out like you have it there, it's not so bad as a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell programmers can often simplify expressions similar to how you'd simplify mathematical expressions. I will show you how to do so in this answer. First, let's look at the building blocks of your expression:

```hs
round    :: Number -> Number
clamp    :: Number -> Number
getScore :: Number -> Number -> Number
```

By composing these three functions we want to create the following function:

```hs
getRoundedClampedScore :: Number -> Number -> Number
getRoundedClampedScore iteration factor = getScore (round iteration) (clamp factor)
```

We can simplify this expression as follows:

```hs
getRoundedClampedScore iteration factor = getScore (round iteration) (clamp factor)
getRoundedClampedScore iteration        = getScore (round iteration) . clamp
getRoundedClampedScore iteration        = (getScore . round) iteration . clamp
getRoundedClampedScore iteration        = (. clamp) ((getScore . round) iteration)
getRoundedClampedScore                  = (. clamp) . (getScore . round)
getRoundedClampedScore                  = (. clamp) . getScore . round
```

If you want to convert this directly into JavaScript then you could do so using reverse function composition:

```
const pipe = f => g => x => g(f(x));

const compose2 = (f, g, h) => pipe(g)(pipe(f)(pipe(h)));

const getRoundedClampedScore = compose2(getScore, round, clamp);

// You'd call it as follows:

getRoundedClampedScore(iteration)(factor);
```

That being said, the best solution would be to simply define it in pointful form:

```js
const compose2 = (f, g, h) => x => y => f(g(x))(h(y));

const getRoundedClampedScore = compose2(getScore, round, clamp);
```

[Pointfree style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) is often useful but sometimes pointless.

Comment: Thank you for this. I genuinely appreciate the Haskell explanation -- it's not a strong language for me, but as time permits I try to learn.