# How to find the type of (\x y z -> x . y z)

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to find the type of `(\x y z -> x . y z)` but haven't had any success in finding the same type as ghci

```
(\x y z -> x . y z) :: (b -> c) -> (t -> a -> b) -> t -> a -> c
```

After removing the infix functions and getting `(\x y z -> (.) x (y z))`, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: In general, you would try to find the type of any sub-expression. The type of (.) is known, and from that you can deduce the types of x and (y z). Maybe try starting with that.

Answer (score 5):

Work backwards, and assign type variables until they are specified:

```
-- We assign types one by one:
(.) x (y z) :: a -- So,
(y z) :: b
(.) x :: b -> a
x :: c
(.) :: c -> b -> a
```

But we know that `(.) :: (y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> (x -> z)`, so, we can equate some types, written with `~`:

```
c ~ y -> z
b ~ x -> y
a ~ x -> z
```

We now know that:

```
x :: y -> z
(.) x (y z) :: x -> z
y z :: x -> y
```

So

```
z :: d
y :: d -> x -> y
```

Finally, we just complete the type of the function

```
--                     (type of x) (Type of y) (type of z) (return type)
(\x y z -> x . y z) :: (y -> z) -> (d -> x -> y) -> d -> (x -> z)
```

Finally, we can ask GHCi for confirmation:

```
Prelude> :t (\x y z -> x . y z)
(\x y z -> x . y z) :: (b -> c) -> (t -> a -> b) -> t -> a -> c
```

Comment: You should note, that you can omit the brackets in the return type to match the signature that ghc calculates.

Answer (score 5):

We can expand the expression `\x y z -> x . y z` as follows:

```hs
  \x y z   -> x . y z
≡ \x y z w -> x (y z w) -- because (f . g) ≡ (\x -> f (g x))
≡ \f g x y -> f (g x y) -- renaming the variables
```

Now, we can look at the types:

```hs
x :: a1
y :: a2

-- Because g is applied to x and y:

g :: (a1 -> a2 -> b)

-- Because f is applied to (g x y):

f :: (b -> c)

-- Therefore:

(\f g x y -> f (g x y)) :: (b -> c) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> a2 -> c
                        -- └──┬───┘    └──────┬──────┘    │     │
                        --    f               g           x     y
```

As you can see, this function just composes `f` and `g`:

```
          ┌───────┐       ┌───────┐
x :: a1 ──┤       │       │       │
          │   g   ├── b ──┤   f   ├── c
y :: a2 ──┤       │       │       │
          └───────┘       └───────┘
```

For more information, take a look at the following question and answer: [What does (f .) . g mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279306/what-does-f-g-mean-in-haskell/20279307#20279307)