# Why >> duplicates right-hand side operand in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

I'm searched for a solution for duplication of a string `n` times. I found `duplicate n str = [1..n] >> str` from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246506/in-haskell-how-can-you-multiply-a-string).
I'm wonder why this method duplicates the `str`.

I search about `>>` and I found this points:

```haskell
k >> f = k >>= \_ -> f
```

and

```haskell
a >> b >> c >> d
-- is is equivalent to
do a
   b
   c
   d
```

Then I try this

```haskell
ghci> do [1..3]; "a"
"aaa"
```

But still I didn't get how it's works. Could anyone explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Monad Laws,

```
a >> b >> c >> d
-- is equivalent to
--                                        (values)   (computations)
do a             do {      a            do {  _x   <-     a
   b                ;      b               ;  _y   <-     b
   c                ;      c               ;  _z   <-     c
   d                ; r <- d               ;   r   <-     d
                    ; return r             ;   return r
                    }                      }
```

and writing it with Monad Comprehensions -- which for lists, non-coincidentally, are exactly the same as List Comprehensions -- it becomes

```
    [ r | _x <- a,  _y <- b,  _z <- c,  r <- d ]
```

which means, in pseudocode,

```
for each _x in a:             for each _x in a:
  for each _y in b:             for each _y in b:
    for each _z in c:             for each _z in c:
      for each r in d:              do  d
         do  yield r
```

so we just "do" the same `d`, over and over, for each *combination of the results* of the actions above it *in the nested fashion*.

For lists this means splicing the elements of `d` into the resulting list of results, repeatedly.

In some sense generalized (nested) loops are what (monads)/applicative/functors *are*, describing the combined computation which is producing the final results from the deepest level just the same:<sup>(*)</sup>

```
  Functor                Applicative                  Monad
    
for x in a:             for x in a                for x in a:
  do  yield (foo x)     and y in b:                 for y in (bar x):
                          do  yield (foo x y)         do  yield (foo x y)

  "loop"                  "loops"                    "nested loops"
                                                   (created on the fly)
```

<sup>(*)</sup> No matter how many levels are there, seen as a whole, the "loops" combo produces its results one by one, just as each "loop" produces its enumeration in separation, one by one. It is so trivial, we don't even notice it with the imperative loops.

Each specific type of Functor gives *its* meaning to the "for", "in" and "do yield", in the above. For lists it means splicing in the results, achieved with `concat`/`concatMap`.

Comment: The explanation was very complete. Thank you

Comment: you're welcome. I invite you to read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info. :)

Answer (score 7):

The definition of `>>=` for lists is `concatMap`: apply a function to each element of the list, then concatenate the results. When you use `>>`, this means applying a function that *ignores* each element of your list, and instead returns the constant value on the right-hand side of `>>`

```
[1..3] >> "a" == [1..3] >>= \_ -> "a"
              == concatMap (\_ -> "a") [1..3]
              == "a" ++ "a" ++ "a"
              == "aaa"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's very confusing if we don't know >>= is concatMap.

Comment: Well, if you want to effectively use the list monad, you should make it a point to know how `(>>=)` works on lists.